# Login window with jComboBox not working

Tags: java, sql

I have created a login where a user can put in their username , password and select their role. When I press Login button nothing happens. Could you please look at my code and tell me what I did wrong :)

class Login.java:

```
    import java.sql.*;



    public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        Connection con =null;
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

    Control c = new Control();


        /**
         * Creates new form Login
         */
        public Login() {
            try {
                initComponents();
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx?user=yyyy&password=zzzzz");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.toString();
            }

        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
         * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
         * regenerated by the Form Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
            user_f = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            pass_f = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            jLabel5.setText("jLabel5");

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setTitle("MyWindow");

            jComboBox1.setMaximumRowCount(2);
            jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Manager", "Staff" }));
            jComboBox1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

            jLabel1.setText("Username");

            jLabel2.setText("Password");

            jLabel3.setText("Role");

            jButton1.setText("Login");
            jButton1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jButton2.setText("Exit");
            jButton2.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fish/oie_transparent (2).png"))); // NOI18N

            javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
            jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
            jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addComponent(jLabel1))
                            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(pass_f)
                                .addComponent(user_f)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, 0, 120, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addContainerGap(121, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addGap(51, 51, 51))
            );

            jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jLabel1, jLabel2, jLabel3});

            jPanel1Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {jButton1, jButton2});

            jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(user_f, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(pass_f, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)))
                        .addComponent(jLabel2))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addGap(29, 29, 29))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addContainerGap())))
            );

            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 225, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );

            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            System.exit(0);
        }                                        

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


               try{
               String user = user_f.getText();
               String pass = pass_f.getText();
               String role = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
               String sql = "Select Log, Pass, Role from Logpass where Log = '"+user+"' Pass = '"+pass+"' Role = '"+role+"' ";
              stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
             rs= stmt.executeQuery();

                if(rs.next()){

                 this.setVisible(false);
               c.setVisible(true);

                    }

                else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong username or password!");

                }
               }
               catch(SQLException e){
               System.out.println(e);
               }

        }                                        


        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /*
             * Set the Nimbus look and feel
             */
            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /*
             * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
             * default look and feel. For details see
             * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
             */
            try {
                for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            //</editor-fold>

            /*
             * Create and display the form
             */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    new Login().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField pass_f;
        private javax.swing.JTextField user_f;
        // End of variables declaration
    }
```

Thank you:)

Comment: Defacing your original post after someone it has been answered it goes against the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Log, Pass and Role from Logpass where Log = '"+user+"' Pass = '"+pass+"' Role = '"+role+"'
```

does not seem like a correct SQL query to me. Try

```
Select Log, Pass, Role from Logpass where Log = '"+user+"' and Pass = '"+pass+"' and Role = '"+role+"'
```

Also, `e.toString();` does not print the exception that might be thrown when executing the query.

Comment: I would say an exception occurs in the `jButton1ActionPerformed` method. Try logging or printing the exception.

Comment: so i printed th exception and this is what it says: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Pass = 'password' Role = 'Manager'' at line 1 i'm quite new and i'm not sure what the syntax error is... any advice please? :)

Comment: It seems you have forgotten the AND keyword between the conditions in the WHERE clause, specifically between the Pass and Role conditions. Check my original answer again.